# Cannot read property role of undefined

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Bueno soy nuevo en Node y viendo video tutoriales cree un crud, pero al momento de usar permisos para administradores tengo error.
Al momento de utilizar la función del middleware verificarUsuario, el usuario pasa como undefined por lo tanto no puede leer la información del role que puede ser user_role o de admin_role. La función es para que solamente aquellos que sean administradores puedan crear usuarios.

```
app.post('/usuario',verificarUsuario, (req, res)=> {
let body = req.body;
let usuario = new Usuario({
    nombre: body.nombre,
    email: body.email,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(body.password, 10),
    role: body.role
});
usuario.save((err, usuarioDB) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400 ).json({
            ok: false,
            err
        });
    }
    res.json({
        ok: true,
        usuario: usuarioDB
    });
});
```

});

```
let verificarUsuario = (req, res, next) => {
const usuario = req.usuario;
if (usuario.role === 'ADMIN_ROLE') {
     next();
 } else {
    return res.json({
         ok: false,
        err: {
             message: 'El usuario no es administrador'
        }
    });
}
```

};

Estas son las capturas del Postman con el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido explica mas tu pregunta para que podas ayudar a resolver el problema

Comment: Bienvenido, Jhon. No lo pongas como comentario; edita tu pregunta y añade toda la información posible.

Comment: No, ya utlize console.log del usuario y es undefined, pero el usuario tiene todas las propiedades de nombre, email, password.

Comment: pero no role que es el que te da error, al intentar a acceder a algo indefinido alli el error

Comment: ¿En qué momento se setea `usuario` a `req`? Se supone debe hacerse dentro de un middleware. ¿Cuál es este?

Comment: Ya lo solucione, coloque un middleware, para setear el usuario asi req.usuario = decoded.usuario GRACIAS !!!!

Comment: De nada. Puedes cerrar la pregunta o colocar la solución por si le sirve a alguien. Saludos.

Comment: por que le pusiste solucionado a tu título?

Comment: no @JHONSOPORTE si encontraste la solución es necesario la publiques abajo en la zona de respuestas, SO en español no funciona colocando en el título de la pregunta solucionado, además de que es muy mal visto